# Convert JSON string to Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a json string like

```
{
    "action":"postRecord", 
     "data":{
            "0":{
                  "lid":999,
                   "cid":1234
                 },
            "1":{
                  "lid":111,
                  "cid":"6789"
                 }
        }
}
```

and

i want it co convert to `Dictionary` object so that i can get the `data` and iterate over it like
    `data[0][lid] = 999`
    `data[0][cid] =1234`
    `data[1][lid] = 111`
    `data[1][cid] = 6789`

The problem is that i have to use `ONLY Native Libraries of .net and I have version 2.0`

Comment: read this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156984/Serialize-JSON-Object-to-String

Comment: you will have to go for `data[0]["cid"] / data[0]["lid"]` as in other cases you will get undefined Error for cid/lid

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use outside libraries? Json.Net is the correct answer and there's a 2.0 version: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: The environment in which i want it to work does not allow Outside DLL may be because of Security Issues

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
Dictionary<string, object> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Convert.ToString(data));
```

using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: I dont want to use any Third party dll. Only Native Libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you can use **.NET 3.5** (I was not sure whether your restriction to .NET 2.0 may be extended to 3.5) then [this other question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net) has [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833839/177710):

```
string json = @"{ ""id"": 13, ""value"": 255 }";

var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
```

You need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` to use that class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was stuck on 2.0 :( . I made a custom class to handle the situation though it take time.